# JS: Write a function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once

Tags: javascript, string, function, for-loop, count

I have the following problem: Count the number of Duplicates

Write a function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string. The input string can be assumed to contain only alphanumeric characters, including digits, uppercase and lowercase alphabets.

Example

- "abcde" -> 0 (# no characters repeats more than once)
- "aabbcde" -> 2 (# 'a' and 'b')
- "aabbcdeB" -> 2 (# 'a' and 'b')
- "indivisibility" -> (1 # 'i')
- "Indivisibilities" -> 2 (# 'i' and 's')
- "aa11" -> 2 (# 'a' and '1')

I have the code below which appears to work but I don't quite understand it:

```
function countDuplicates(str) {
    var myObj = {},
        counter = 0;    
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){   

      if(!myObj[str[i]]){
          myObj[str[i]] = 1;
      } 
      else if(myObj[str[i]] < 2) {
          myObj[str[i]]+=1;
          counter++;
      }    
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Would it be possible to go through line by line and provide a quick explanation of what the code is doing?

Comment: The task was to *write* the function, not copy-paste it. If you don't understand the code, try debugging it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to go through line by line and provide a quick explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: I think the code is going to fail for this particular requisite: `case-insensitive`. As a little help, while the code is iterating over the characters of the string, it is making an object where the `keys` are the characters and the `values` are the frequencies of those character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This code is going throught all characters in string
2. You are creating an empty object `myObj`
3. Adding property to `myObj`, with the same name as value of the currently checking character i.e. `myObj[str[i]]` you can decompose it as:
   `str[i]` is equal `g` so you will have `myObject['g']`
   and then assign number `1` to `myObject['g']` so your object now looks like:

   myObj: {
    g: 1
   }
4. Checking next charater of the string, now the charakter is e.g. `c`, so you are doing the same operation as in pt.3, now you object looks like:

   myObj: {
        g: 1, c: 1
       }
5. But what happen if you already have an added character to `myObj`, this is checking in `if(!myObj[str[i]]){...}`, so what is happening here, is that we are checking if currently checked charaker is already added in the object. If not added then add it with value `1` as in pt.3 
   `e.g. !myObj[str[i]]` is the same as `myObj['c'] === undefined` (if is undefined, add it to object)
   But if it is already added we are checking if the value of the object property is less then `2` (we want to increment counter only once for specified character), if yes we are incrementing `counter` (yep we have found the duplicate)
6. Return counter

Answer (score 2):

```
function duplicateCount(text) {
    var nText = text.toLowerCase(); //this changes every character to lower case 
    var myObj = {}; // Declaring an empty object
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nText.length; i++) {
    // assigning character as property and giving value 1 
        if (!myObj[nText[i]]){
            myObj[nText[i]] = 1;
        }//checking if character already added
        else if (myObj[nText[i]] < 2) {
            myObj[nText[i]] += 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function countDuplicates(text) {
  return text.toLowerCase().split('').filter((val, i, arr) => {
    return !!(arr.indexOf(val) !== i && arr.lastIndexOf(val) === i);
  }).length;
}
```